# DHCP IP address lookup

Tags: powershell, dhcp

So I have another basic PowerShell thing that I am not quite advanced enough to figure out. I have a couple of scripts that I use to look up info in AD (one I provide info from the description field the other I enter the computer number) What I would like to take onto those is pulling IP address leases from DHCP. I need to pull it from there for MS Surface device issues. I also have 2 servers that I need to poll for IP leases....

The bit I have start on but I am getting really mixed results

```
 $scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName 'XXXXXXX- need to have 2 here if possible XXXX' 
foreach($scope in $scopes)
{
    #write-host "The current scope name is:" $scope.name -ForegroundColor Red
    $lease = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName 'XXXXXXX- need to have 2 here if possible XXXX' -ScopeId $scope.ScopeId
    #$lease
}
    $pro = @{'name'=$scope.Name;'ipaddress'=$lease.IPAddress;'ScopeId'=$lease.ScopeId;'ClientId'=$lease.ClientId} | Format-Table
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $pro
    $obj | Format-Table
```

I know I am not explaining this well - but ultimately I would like to enter a computer number and have it pull up the AD information and then go into DHCP and pull the leases.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$DHCPServer = "Your Server Name"

$entry = Read-Host "Enter in computer name"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$computerObject = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $entry} -Properties Name, DNSHostname

    $lease = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DHCPServer -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module ServerManager
    $info = Get-DHCPServerv4scope | Get-DHCPServerv4Lease | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -eq "$($using:computerObject.DNSHostName)"}
    return $info    
} -Credential
$lease
```

**$lease** will be all your scope information and the **$computerObject** should have all your AD information for that computer. If you want more AD properties, you can just remove Name, DNSRecord and replace it with a * for all

Comment: With the original version of that I got DHCP errors as it was trying to use my computer as the server so I made some changes and now I don't get any results

Comment: '$entry = Read-Host "Enter in computer name"

$computerObject = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -eq $entry} -Properties Name, DNSHostname

$lease = Get-DHCPServerv4scope -ComputerName 'SERVERINFOHERE' | Get-DHCPServerv4Lease -ComputerName 'SERVERINFOHERE' | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -eq "$($computerObject.DNSHostName)"}'

Comment: The DHCPServer4Scope needs to run on a server 2012 and newer.  I have updated the script to work on a local machine

Comment: I have updated the script to prompt for credentials for the DHCP server. You only need this if your current account does not have permissions to that server.  Also, make sure you are running powershell as admin